# Ubuntu 22.04 really strange audio problems when playing videos with vlc/videos app, but no problems in web browser

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, video, vlc

**I'm not even sure how to start troubleshooting this**. I have some .mp4 files that when I try playing them I'm getting choppy audio when opening with vlc/videos app. If I open the same files with Firefox there's no problem playing anything. I can play the same files on another system that's still running Ubuntu 20.04 and I have no issues opening any of the .mp4 files. To add more to the mystery some of the .mp4 files play fine in videos app and other times the video is just a green screen while audio is working. Any suggestions? I haven't found anything on stack.

The kernel on the 22.04 desktop:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic              5.15.0-43.46                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic              5.15.0-48.54                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic              5.15.0-50.56                               amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04              5.15.0.50.50                               amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

except I have `ic  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic` on the first line from the laptop, otherwise, everything else is the same. I did have `linux-image-5.15.0-43-generic` on there before and there was no problem playing videos.

This is the kernel from my Ubuntu 20.04:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ic  linux-image-5.15.0-46-generic              5.15.0-46.49~20.04.1                                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic              5.15.0-48.54~20.04.1                                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-50-generic              5.15.0-50.56~20.04.1                                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04              5.15.0.50.56~20.04.19                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.11.0-46-generic     5.11.0-46.51~20.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-52-generic     5.13.0-52.59~20.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-43-generic     5.15.0-43.46~20.04.1                                   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: Your title says you are running Ubuntu Core 22 and 20 is that correct? Only Ubuntu Core uses a single digit version number.

Comment: Please don't post duplicates [ubuntu 22.04 choppy audio when playing local media/offline audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431831/ubuntu-22-04-choppy-audio-when-playing-local-media-offline-audio)

Comment: @David I'm using ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso it's not Ubuntu Core.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I completely forgot I posted that earlier. I deleted it, thank you.

Comment: Then the body of the question needs an edit.